# Get image with wget when I have full path to it

Tags: image, bash, wget

I'm trying to get an image each hour with wget. I have full path to it, but I can't get it working. 
Here's the code

```
DATE="date +%s"
TIMESTAMP=`$DATE`
cd /path_to/photofolder/
wget http://path_to_image/jpg/image.jpg
mv image.jpg image1.jpg
FILENAME="$TIMESTAMP.jpg"
cp image1.jpg $FILENAME
```

Comment: "I can't get it working" doesn't provide enough information. Please be more specific.

Comment: Slightly not related to your question, but you can shorten your script to one command: wget -rnv http ://path_to_image/jpg/image.jpg -O /path_to/photofolder/\`date +%s\`.jpg

Comment: well no images are created at all. I've tried this script:
cd /path_to_photo_folder/
mkdir nonono
and it doesnt create directory also

Comment: Why not this one-liner instead of all that: `wget -O "/path/to/photofolder/$(date +%s).jpg" http://path_to_image/jpg/image.jpg`

Comment: @user2004170 How did you execute this script? What was the output?